# How to make three duplicated if condition with show() and hide() in one method in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Use jquery-3.4.1.min.js

I use if-elseif to show a different id value based on the selection below.
When the page is loaded it shows id1 by default.
But as you see there are duplications except which one will be shown based on select. So wondering if there is a way to use only one except three if else?

```js
$("#id1").show();
$("#id2").hide();
$("#id3").hide();

$('.id-select').on('change', function() {
  if ( this.value == '1') {
    $("#id1").show();
    $("#id2").hide();
    $("#id3").hide();
  }
  else if( this.value == '2') {
    $("#id1").hide();
    $("#id2").show();
    $("#id3").hide();
  }
  else if( this.value == '3') {
    $("#id1").hide();
    $("#id2").hide();
    $("#id3").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="my-select">
  <option value="1">id1</option>
  <option value="2">id2</option>
  <option value="3">id3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What's the HTML structure?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the controls dynamically using starts with `^`. So something like...

```
$('.id-select').on('change', function(){
    $("[id^='id']").hide()// hide all of them
    $("#id" + $(this).val()).show()// show the one with the correct value
});
```

Obviously this is on the assumption that you have the same naming convention for your control id's.

More info on the jquery documentation... https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Dang, beat me to it.

Comment: Yes, but perhaps there is also `id4` that is unrelated? We need to see the HTML structure (Or the OP should accept the answer)

Comment: @AlonEitan id4 would work in this instance too providing it's in the `<select>`

Comment: Correct, but if not, it will be hidden

Comment: @AlonEitan I think it's safe to infer it will be in the select from the way the question was phrased :)

Comment: OK, you convinced me :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a simpler way. [Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/b8Lzuwd6/1/)
You could add an extra class to all the elements you wish to toggle or use @Sean T's selector. It all depends on your HTML markup.

Here's an example

HTML

```
<select class="my-select">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">id1</option>
  <option value="2">id2</option>
  <option value="3">id3</option>
</select>

<div id="id1" class="box">ID #1</div>
<div id="id2" class="box">ID #2</div>
<div id="id3" class="box">ID #3</div>
```

JS

```
$('.my-select').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val(); //get the value
  $('.box').hide(); //hide all of them
  $('#id' + value).show(); //show the correct one
});

$('document').ready(function() {
  //trigger the change to run the process once
  $('.my-select').trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the selected option value into the id selector tag:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id1").show();
  $("#id2, #id3").hide();

  $('.my-select').on('change', function() {
    $("#id1, #id2, #id3").hide();
    $("#id" + this.value).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="my-select">
  <option value="1">id1</option>
  <option value="2">id2</option>
  <option value="3">id3</option>
</select>
<div id="id1">ID 1</div>
<div id="id2">ID 2</div>
<div id="id3">ID 3</div>
```

With pure Javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   const divs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=id]");
   divs.forEach((el, idx) => el.style.display = idx === 0 ? "block" : "none");
   
   document.querySelector(".my-select").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
       divs.forEach((el, idx) => el.style.display = e.target.value == ++idx ? "block" : "none");
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="my-select">
  <option value="1">id1</option>
  <option value="2">id2</option>
  <option value="3">id3</option>
</select>
<div id="id1">ID 1</div>
<div id="id2">ID 2</div>
<div id="id3">ID 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways to do it, I personally use classes as css but theres many different choices, it really depends on your html.

html

```
<div class="item item-1 active">test</div>
<div class="item item-2">test</div>
<div class="item item-3">test</div>
```

css

```
<style>.item {display:none;} .item.active {display: block;}</style>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.id-select').on('change', function() { 
        $('.item').removeClass('active'); 
        $('.item-'+$(this).val()).addClass('active') 
    }):
});
```